# Include Joomla Component outside Joomla 1.5 (Joomla FB Chat)

Tags: php, joomla, components, joomla1.5

Is there anyone know how to include Joomla Component to be worked outside Joomla?
I have a project for my undergraduate program to make a website but i were not allowed to used CMS like joomla or wordpress..
Is anyone know how to make this thing happens work in PHP?

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks,
Ricky L

Answer (score 0):

Joomla Platform [here](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-platform) combined with an extension such a [JomSocial](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/communities/7608) would probably give you the result your after. But you would then have to add in your own display/model code I suspect. As I think that gets packaged up with the CMS these days

Comment: JomSocial would require the Joomla CMS.

Comment: Just because of the JView etc classes? or because of other functions it relies on in the cms library?

Comment: Extensions use the CMS for models and access control and lots of other things. But honestly I think for a homework assignment you are probably not supposed to be copying a Joomla component, that is why the professor said not to use a cms. You can be inspired by it and you could ask if you can use the platform but not the cms.

Comment: Thanks for the comment guys, @Elin My Undergraduate purpose, is to create non CMS website but it must have 5 function (Chat, Video Call, etc). My Chat and Video call function, is already works in Joomla. So i only need to take it, outside from joomla..

Can't wait for another suggestions